# django3 file upload default permission is 420?

Tags: django-3.0, centos8

I maid picture upload function as shopping management.

web:
http://www.henojiya.net/shopping/

source:
https://github.com/duri0214/Portfolio/tree/master/mysite/shopping

Now, I problem this.
permission error.

log:
https://github.com/duri0214/Portfolio/issues/25

I was look at log message.

```
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
420
```

420???

I think django default permission is 644.

official document:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions

local upload test is ok!
I want picture upload.

thank you

```
add info
drwxr-xr-x. op op mysite
└drwxrwxr-x. op op shopping
　└drwxrwxr-x. op op static
　　└drwxrwxr-x. op op shopping
　　　└drwxrwxr-x. op op img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I fixed it.

I didn't know the role of "media" in "setting.py".
django want to save to '[example.com]/media' if add write to 'setting.py'
I am no edit apache file.

```
# setting.py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In 'models.py', if upload_to ='shopping/' is set, it will be saved as [example.com] /media/shopping/xxx.jpg

```
# models.py
class Products(models.Model):
    """product"""
    code = models.CharField('code', max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField('product_name', max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField('product_price', default=0)
    description = models.TextField('description')
    picture = models.ImageField('picture', upload_to='shopping/')
```